# Listview Display issue

Tags: android, listview

I am pretty new to android. I am trying to create a test app that will show the call log name and number. User can select it to see more details. I have ListActivity class to show Call the Call Log. This is called from the main activity (main activity has buttons and is housed inside a Tab activity). I am using the standard single line layout from android to display the number. List is displayed fine, but when I scroll, alternate items are selected. After some scrolling, the caching is really bad (each number stacked on top of another).

The code as such works fine if I use in a different project - listview is shown and scrolling etc works fine. I am not able to figure out what specifically in my original app is causing the issue. When I call the android contacts Intent, it works fine. My code to call the list is

```
public class callLog extends ListActivity {
private ListView list;
private ArrayList<String> cLNumber = new ArrayList<String>(); 
private HashSet<String> remDupl = new HashSet<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.logview);
    list = getListView();


    cLNumber.add("Test 1");
    cLNumber.add("Test 2");
    cLNumber.add("Test 3");
    cLNumber.add("Test 4");
    cLNumber.add("Test 5");
    cLNumber.add("Test 6");
    cLNumber.add("Test 7");
    cLNumber.add("Test 8");
    cLNumber.add("Test 9");
    cLNumber.add("Test 10");
    cLNumber.add("Test 11");
    cLNumber.add("Test 12");
    cLNumber.add("Test 13");
    cLNumber.add("Test 14");
    cLNumber.add("Test 15");
    cLNumber.add("Test 16");
    cLNumber.add("Test 17");

  //Remove Duplicates
    remDupl.addAll(cLNumber);
    cLNumber.clear();
    cLNumber.addAll(remDupl);

    ArrayAdapter<String> cLogList = new ArrayAdapter<String>    (this.getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cLNumber);
     list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);  
     list.setAdapter(cLogList);
}}
```

See the screenshot [here](http://img202.imageshack.us/g/screenshot0bj.png)

I tried different options and I am starting to look at TableLayout a backup option. Did any one faced a similar issue? 
[The screen shot is from android 1.5 emulator, but its happening on 2.1 as well as on devices]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe that this is similar to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201091/listview-row-overlap-problem Hope that helps! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I checked and in my case, layout_height is set as fill_parent. When I did some more analysis, i can see that the list view is getting duplicated each time I touch it using finger on the device or while scrolling. When I scroll, looks like the top layer is scrolling and therefore it is creating ghost images. I am unable to understand why this is occurring. I deactivated all the touchListeners etc, but still this is occurring.

Comment: Nailed it: issue was android:theme="@style/Theme.NoBackground" in the manifest. Not sure why. I removed it and listview is scrolling fine.